# How to drag and drop object no jquery

Tags: javascript

Ok, I feel like this should have already been asked on stackoverflow, but apparently it hasn't. How do you make an object draggable using no jQuery?

I understand how to make an object move on the hovering of the mouse so it contantly follows it, and tried to apply it to mousedown instead of mousemove and set it on an interval of every 10 milliseconds, but with no success.

So here is what I have:

```
    document.querySelector(".box").addEventListener(function(e) {
      let s = document.querySelector(".box");
      var e = e || window.event;
      let run = setInterval(function() {
        s.style.marginLeft = e.clientX + "px";
        s.style.marginTop = e.clientY + "px";
        getMouseCoords(e);
      }, 10);
    });
```

So how would I drag and drop an object without any jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this. It uses only pure JavaScript.
Simply you can drag div content

```
<div id="draggable-element">Drag me!</div>
```

[Link for Draggable Project](https://jsfiddle.net/tovic/Xcb8d/)

Comment: So, I tried this and added it to my codepen, and it isn't working... here is the link: https://codepen.io/TheAndersMan/pen/KmNoPR?editors=0011

Comment: @TheAndersMan you added all the code from jsfiddle link, there is some more of your previous code left, and .box(class) also not defined. remove your code part, it works fine.

Comment: @Durga I have that code, for another part of the project and can't get rid of it. Also I changed the code to work for .box

Answer (score 0):

There is a really good codepen example I've used in the past for this:

https://codepen.io/byronglover/pen/oxjgEK

**Step 1 - create containers for the objects**

```
<!--First Drop Target-->
<div data-drop-target="true">
    <div id="box1" draggable="true" class="box navy"></div>
    <div id="box2" draggable="true" class="box red"></div>
    <div id="box3" draggable="true" class="box green"></div>
    <div id="box4" draggable="true" class="box orange"></div>
    <div id="box5" draggable="true" class="box navy"></div>
    <div id="box6" draggable="true" class="box red"></div>
    <div id="box7" draggable="true" class="box green"></div>
    <div id="box8" draggable="true" class="box orange"></div>
</div>

<!--Second Drop Target-->
<div data-drop-target="true"></div>
```

**Step 2 - apply some javascript invoking draggable and data-drop-target and event listeners**

```
//Function handleDragStart(), Its purpose is to store the id of the draggable element.
    function handleDragStart(e) {
        e.dataTransfer.setData("text", this.id); //note: using "this" is the same as using: e.target.
    }//end function


    //The dragenter event fires when dragging an object over the target. 
    //The css class "drag-enter" is append to the targets object.
    function handleDragEnterLeave(e) {
        if(e.type == "dragenter") {
            this.className = "drag-enter" 
        } else {
            this.className = "" //Note: "this" referces to the target element where the "dragenter" event is firing from.
        }
    }//end function



    //Function handles dragover event eg.. moving your source div over the target div element.
    //If drop event occurs, the function retrieves the draggable element’s id from the DataTransfer object.
    function handleOverDrop(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
  //Depending on the browser in use, not using the preventDefault() could cause any number of strange default behaviours to occur.
        if (e.type != "drop") {
            return; //Means function will exit if no "drop" event is fired.
        }
        //Stores dragged elements ID in var draggedId
        var draggedId = e.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        //Stores referrence to element being dragged in var draggedEl
        var draggedEl = document.getElementById(draggedId);

        //if the event "drop" is fired on the dragged elements original drop target e.i..  it's current parentNode, 
        //then set it's css class to ="" which will remove dotted lines around the drop target and exit the function.
        if (draggedEl.parentNode == this) {
            this.className = "";
            return; //note: when a return is reached a function exits.
        }
        //Otherwise if the event "drop" is fired from a different target element, detach the dragged element node from it's
        //current drop target (i.e current perantNode) and append it to the new target element. Also remove dotted css class. 
        draggedEl.parentNode.removeChild(draggedEl);
        this.appendChild(draggedEl); //Note: "this" references to the current target div that is firing the "drop" event.
        this.className = "";
    }//end Function



    //Retrieve two groups of elements, those that are draggable and those that are drop targets:
    var draggable = document.querySelectorAll('[draggable]')
    var targets = document.querySelectorAll('[data-drop-target]');
//Note: using the document.querySelectorAll() will aquire every element that is using the attribute defind in the (..)


    //Register event listeners for the"dragstart" event on the draggable elements:
    for(var i = 0; i < draggable.length; i++) {
        draggable[i].addEventListener("dragstart", handleDragStart);
    }

    //Register event listeners for "dragover", "drop", "dragenter" & "dragleave" events on the drop target elements.
    for(var i = 0; i < targets.length; i++) {
        targets[i].addEventListener("dragover", handleOverDrop);
        targets[i].addEventListener("drop", handleOverDrop);
        targets[i].addEventListener("dragenter", handleDragEnterLeave);
        targets[i].addEventListener("dragleave", handleDragEnterLeave);
    }
```

**And Finally some CSS to tie it all together**

```
h2 {
  color: #a7a3a4;
  margin-left: 80px;
}

[data-drop-target] {
            height: 400px;
            width: 200px;
            margin: 25px;
            background-color: gainsboro;
            float: left;
        }
        .drag-enter {
            border: 2px dashed #000;
        }
        .box {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
      float: left;
        }
    .box:nth-child(3) {
      clear: both;
    }
        .navy {
            background-color: navy;
        }
        .red {
            background-color: firebrick;
        }
    .green {
            background-color: darkgreen;
        }
        .orange {
            background-color: orange;
        }
```

**Summary**

The long and short of it is that the draggable content needs to have some sort of event listener to bind to it for this to work effectively.

Let me know if you have any other questions and I will do my best to help!

Comment: Sorry, this isn't what I meant by "drag and drop", I meant anywhere on the screen, but thanks anyway!

Comment: No worries. Expanding on your reply to Harsha W, your codepen appears to reference .box which doesn't exist in your HTML. try: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rmjwoX?editors=1111